# VBA Remove duplicates taking 30 minutes to run with no idea why

Tags: excel, dictionary, vba

So the code below copies data from two columns in one sheet. Pastes these so that values are displayed in another sheet (because one column is a formula =Left(Column+1,4)) and then attempts to run a remove duplicates across the two columns that are pasted.

This takes roughly 30 minutes to run on what is essentially 100k cells (2 columns of 50k rows each).

This is what I've been using

```
Sub ProjTrending1()

Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
Dim St As Date, Et As Date
Dim Tt As Double

St = Time

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Defines S1 as a Worksheet
Set s1 = Sheets("All Data")

'Defines S2 as WorkSheet
Set s2 = Sheets("Workings")

'Defines LastR1
Dim LR1 As Long
Dim LR2 As Long

'Finds last row cell working sheet

LR2 = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

'Takes Data from Order Column of defined data Sheet and copy & pastes it to Working Sheet Column B
s1.Range("J1:J" & LR2).Copy s2.Range("A1")

s1.Range("e1:e" & LR2).Copy

s2.Range("b1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

LR1 = s2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

'Removes Duplicates from Column B Working sheet
s2.Range("A2:B" & LR1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo


'Copies the formula from C2 and applies it to all cells in column C where column A has values (simple concatenate + countifs(B$2:B2,B2)
s2.Range("C2").Copy s2.Range("C2:C" & LR1)

Et = Time

Tt = (Et - St) * 24 * 60 * 60

MsgBox Timetaken


End Sub
```

I've also tried using a dictionary to do this but I'm new to dictionaries so whilst the code looks good compared to my usual attempts its because its taken from a couple of different sources. (Copied and Pasted the data to sheet2 incase this overwrote the source data)

```
Sub M_delete_duplicates()
sn = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Resize(, 5)

With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
For j = 1 To UBound(sn)
.Item(sn(j, 1)) = Application.Index(sn, j, 0)
Next

Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 4).Resize(.Count, UBound(sn, 2)) = Application.Index(.Items, 0, 0)
End With
```

End Sub

This is as slow to run and it only does remove duplicates based on single column and I need it to operate on two columns. The potential way around this is to concatenate the two columns of data and run the remove duplicates once and then break the data using =right(Value,X)

If wanted to do it manually it takes 30 seconds max. It makes no sense to me as to why it takes so long to run.

Can anyone help with why this might be taking so long to run? and how I might modify the dictionary code to remove duplicates over two columns?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Have a look at my answer here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43116101/3042759) It does what you're talking about using dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

Updated from my comment. This uses a dictionary to track which rows have been added and then copies unique rows across to the destination sheet. You may want to modify it a bit for your use (e.g. update sheet names) **Always test this first on a copy of your data set or make a back up before running code**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ExampleRemoveDuplicates()
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim temp As String
    Dim calc As String
    Dim headers As Variant
    Dim NoCol As Long, NoRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim c, key

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        calc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    ' Change this to the sheet that is applicable
    With Sheet1
        NoCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ' Assumes first row of sheet is headers
        headers = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, NoCol)).Value2
        ' Change this to destination sheet
        With Sheet2
            .Cells.Clear
            .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, NoCol)).Value2 = headers
        End With
        For Each c In .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
            ReDim arr(1 To NoCol)
            j = 1
            Do
                arr(j) = c.Offset(0, j - 1).Value2
                j = j + 1
            Loop Until j = NoCol + 1
            temp = Join(arr, "//")
            If Not dict.exists(temp) And Not temp = vbNullString Then
                dict.Add key:=temp, Item:=arr
                ' Change this to destination sheet
                With Sheet2
                    NoRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    .Range(.Cells(NoRow, 1), .Cells(NoRow, NoCol)).Value2 = arr
                End With
            End If
        Next c
    End With
    i = 1

    ReDim Results(1 To dict.Count, 1 To NoCol)
    For Each key In dict.keys
        For j = 1 To NoCol
            Results(i, j) = dict(key)(j)
        Next j
        i = i + 1
    Next key

    ' Change this to destination sheet
    With Sheet2.Cells(1, 1)
        .Range(.Offset(1, 0), .Offset(dict.Count, NoCol - 1)) = Results
    End With

    With Application
        .Calculation = calc
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```