# Delete rows from sheet where match is found in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet which has just over a thousand lines and I need to be delete all ROWS in it which are as follows:

column A, B,C,D,E,F AND G  MUST be an exact match.

Column H (hours) must have a negative value which matches the same value but positive forming a pair, then the pair is deleted.

so the following is an example of  a match:

```
date    prod    Item    Title   Code    person      number  hours
2016    xxx     123     test    a12d    John Smith  78901   8
2016    xxx     123     test    a12d    John Smith  78901   -8
2016    xxx     123     test    a12d    John Smith  78901   -8
2016    xxx     123     test    a12d    John Smith  78901   -42
```

resulting in:

```
date    prod    Item    Title   Code    person      number  hours
2016    xxx     123     test    a12d    John Smith  78901   -8
2016    xxx     123     test    a12d    John Smith  78901   -42
```

I'm having trouble explaining it let alone writing a macro!

```
Dim LR As Long
Dim i As Long

'Remove rows 
LR = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = LR To 1 Step -1
    'How do i compare it against other rows?
Next i
```

Comment: In your matching example `date`, `item` and `number` do not match but you say column A to G *must* match? What now?

Comment: @Peh sorry example was wrong corrected, sorry...

Comment: Is it allowed to sort the rows? Because comparing sorted data is much easier.

Comment: Look into WorksheetFunction.Match Method

Comment: @peh, yes we can sort the rows if that helps.

Comment: @0m3r, i will take a look but think i'm getting out of my depth!

Comment: Another question: Do we need to find *pairs* of matches or *any* matches? I mean if we have 3 rows where columns A-G are matching but hours are `8`, `-8`, `8` do we delete pairwise (one `8` and one `-8` row, the other `8` remains) or do we delete all 3 rows?

Comment: In your example which one gets deleted? 8 or -8?

Comment: Can you share more example before and after results

Comment: sorry having trouble expressing it, have updated the example, looking for negative positive pairs, however i don't think there would be a third line matching but technically it is possible. the negative AND positive pair are deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to join all of the columns together using a delimiter and add it to a dictionary as the key. This will only hold unique values. You could then split each one back into columns again and overwrite the whole sheet. There wold be many other ways to achieve this though and this is just an example of one way you could do it. Also, **as always if you do try this try it first on a copy of your original data in case of any unexpected behaviour**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ExampleRemoveDuplicates()
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim temp As String
    Dim calc As String
    Dim headers As Variant
    Dim NoCol As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim c, key

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        calc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    ' Change this to the sheet that is applicable
    With Sheet1
        NoCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ' Assumes first row of sheet is headers
        headers = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, NoCol)).Value2
        For Each c In .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
            ReDim arr(1 To NoCol)
            temp = vbNullString
            j = 1
            Do
                arr(j) = c.Offset(0, j - 1).Value2
                If j = 8 Then
                    temp = temp & Abs(arr(j))
                Else
                    temp = temp & arr(j)
                End If
                j = j + 1
            Loop Until j = NoCol + 1

            If Not dict.exists(temp) And Not temp = vbNullString Then dict.Add key:=temp, Item:=arr
        Next c
        .Cells.ClearContents
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, NoCol)).Value2 = headers
        i = 1
        ReDim Results(1 To dict.Count, 1 To NoCol)
        For Each key In dict.keys
            For j = 1 To NoCol
                Results(i, j) = dict(key)(j)
            Next j
            i = i + 1
        Next key
        With .Cells(1, 1)
            .Range(.Offset(1, 0), .Offset(dict.Count, NoCol - 1)) = Results
        End With
    End With

    With Application
        .Calculation = calc
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Tom, when i try this i get a type mismatch on the "temp =..." line ?

Comment: `Application.Transpose` is a simple way to do it but can cause issues. I've removed this. Can you give it another try now and see if you have any issues?

Comment: Can you try again. I've removed the `Application.Transpose` which can cause issues dependent on string lengths

Comment: thanks @Tom it now runs but doesn't give the desired results, I have tried to understand your code but it a bit beyond my current level!
the results I'm looking is to only retain in the sheet the rows which are unique, given that H -x needs to +x.  e.g. if A to G are the same and H is the same or if  -H == +H (e,g, -5 should be considered a match with +5.

Comment: @Adrian Right think I missed that. so column H should be compared but should be regardless of whether it is postiive or negative? Other then that is everything as expected?

Comment: correct re H.
and both matching rows deleted.
thus only leaving the unique rows

Comment: @Adrian Have just updated this to treat both positive and negative values the same by taking the absolute of column H. Can you try it again. Have also made quite a few speed improvements in it too.

Comment: Thank you this seems to work and I will now try to learn from it!

Answer (score 1):

I think (meaning I didn't test :-)) this should do the job.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteMatchingRow()
    ' 30 Mar 2017

    Dim Rl As Long
    Dim R As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        Rl = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For R = Rl To 2 Step -1
            If FindMatch(CompString(.Rows(R)), Val(.Cells(R, 8).Value), R) Then
                .Rows(R).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Treu
End Sub

Private Function FindMatch(ByVal Comp1 As String, _
                           ByVal Gval As Integer, _
                           ByVal LR As Long) As Long
    ' 30 Mar 2017
    ' return the row number where a match was found
    ' or return 0, if no match was found

    Dim R As Long
    Dim Comp2 As String

    With ActiveSheet
        For R = LR To 1 Step -1
            Comp2 = CompString(.Rows(R))
            If StrComp(Comp1, Comp2, vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
                If .Cells(R, 8).Value = (Gval * -1) Then
                    FindMatch = R
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        Next R
    End With
End Function

Private Function CompString(Row As Range) As String
    ' 30 Mar 2017

    Dim Fun As String
    Dim C As Long

    With Row
        For C = 1 To 7
            Fun = Fun & CStr(.Cells(C).Value)
        Next C
    End With
    CompString = Fun
End Function
```

The code prepares two strings consisting of A+B+C+D+E+F (all as strings, not numbers) and compares them. If they are identical, the value in column G is compares with its pendent in the match row * -1. If the two values are identical the row is identified as a match.

The function CompString prepares the comparison strings. The function FindMatch finds the match, and the main routine DeleteMatchingRow does the deleting. I don't have the data to test it on, but in theory it sounds good, doesn't it?

You can use the following function to get a visual of rows which you consider matching but the code doesn't.

```
Private Sub TestMatch()
    ' 31 Mar 2017

    Dim R As Long

    R = 3
    With ActiveSheet
        Debug.Print CompString(.Rows(R)), "Column G has "; .Cells(R, 8).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Paste this code in the same code sheet as the function CompString. Make sure that the sheet from which you want to read a line is active (look at it before switching to the VBE window). Replace the value 3 in the code with the number of the row you wish to read. The compare string will be printed in the VB Editor's Immediate Window (press Ctl+G if you don't see it). Repeat the exercise with the other string. You can then compare them visually and determine why VBA considers them different.

Comment: Sorting the data before applying the above code will speed up the process, but it isn't essential.

Comment: Also, this could be sped up by `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning of `DeleteMatchingRow` and setting it back on with `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end

Comment: Thank you @Variatus, when I run this it removes some lines but leaves some which do meet the criteria! i did comment out the Dim LR As Long within the function as it caused an error!

Comment: Yes the superfluous re-declaration of RL should cause an error. I removed the line from the above code as well and added the two lines about ScreenUpdating suggested by Tom. Then I added a procedure for testing and instructions how to use it. Please read at the bottom of the solution above.

Comment: Thanks, although I marked the other solution as the answer I was able to learn a lot form you solution many thanks